# LSD (LSDeluxe) in Git Bash

Tags: git-bash, ls

I have tried using LSD and I have a small problem when I use it in CMD it looks very good.  [LSD in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8c5O.png)

But when I type LSD in Git Bash the colors are not there but just some text [LSD in Git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13DSA.png)

Does anyone, know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to a bug which will be fixed soon, the temp fix is setting an alias to .bashrc

**step 1: open git bash**

if you have vscode

```
 code ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
 nano ~/.bashrc
```

**step 2: copy the following command to .bashrc**

```
alias ls="TERM=dumb lsd"
```

**step 3: save the file and close the git bash terminal**

**step 4: reopen the git bash terminal and try using `ls` instead of `lsd` it should work when you use `ls`**

ref link: https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd/issues/657#issuecomment-1128721665

also make sure you have the necessary fonts: https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd#prerequisites